# Switching from Dual Boot to Virtual Box

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization

I am dual booting on my Lenovo t420 windows and Ubuntu. I am using both Os and find it annoying to switch back and forth...I was wondering if I could have Ubuntu on my Virtual Box and copy my information from the Dual Boot to the windows partition. I have lots of stuff on my Linux, mainly because of eclipse and android stuff.

Comment: I like the t420, its a nice laptop

Comment: @Stephan...Thanks Man...its good to know people appreciate Lenovo and stuff over just macbook all the time. Btw...Do you have an asnwer to my q?

Comment: lol nope, no idea.  I am however, doing the same thing you are on my t510

Comment: +1 because the existing downvote is undeserved and unexplained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this link:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9323

it is possible that this may not work because when an OS is installed, it loads only the files to make it run on your specific machine. the simulated hardware in virtualbox might be too different that what it uses now.(I know this because I tried this with win xp)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows 7, you can use 'Windows Virtual PC', which is built in to Windows 7, to run a Linux OS as virtual machine.  See http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/366-how-to-run-linux-under-windows-7s-windows-virtual-pc/ for more info.

Comment: @mti2935...Thank You...but how do i copy files to the new Linux that i create from my old linux

Comment: You can copy files from one instance to the other by way of scp or ftp, rsync, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm T420 with both Ubuntu(12.04 64bit) and Win7 too. Normally I can see Win7 partition be mount to Ubuntu and I can copy data from Ubuntu to Win7.